# IntelliJ: find method by signature

Tags: intellij-idea

I wonder if it's possible to find method of object which returns specific type?
For example I want to look in autocompletion all methods which return `String`:

[image]

For this example it's easy to find it just by scrolling down, but for objects with large number of methods it can be painful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually there is no default sorting by return type(yet?), even in class structure view.
I'm using smart completion(ctrl+shift+space) for this purposes in place where only certain type is accepted, for example:

```
String s = aClass.<smart completion here>
```

It will show methods from a `aClass` that return `String` at the beginning.

Comment: yeah, i've thought already about this 'workaround'. It seems that we should write feature request :)

Comment: And 5 years later this question has an answer, the functionality is implemented in ItelliJ under Edit > Find > Search Structurally. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48025053/1085370