# How to easily find/search in IDE(specially in IntelliJ), which methods returns int type and also takes string as parameter in java?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, ide, structural-search

so if I put the keywords.. 
return type:int, parameter:String (something like this)
it show results such as 
void int Integer.parseInt(String)

Hope I could explain what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try Structural Search and Replace (`Edit | Find | Search Structurally...`). There you can use a pattern like the following:

```
int $method$(String $param$);
```

to find all methods which return an `int` and take one `String` parameter.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet but this sounds promising. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to search methods by its signature(arguments + return type). There was a bit similiar question here: [IntelliJ: find method by signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13800276/intellij-find-method-by-signature)

Invoking ctrl+shift+space on:

```
Function<String, Integer> f =
```

returns only `String::hashCode`, `String::length`, and `Integer::new`. It misses `Integer.parseInt` and probably thousands of other methods that have same signature. The huge amount of possible results is probably a reason why such search isn't am IDE feature.